# Ошибка Laravel при редактировании

Tags: laravel-5.7

Всем привет! Работаю на Laravel и хотел лишь изменить данные и на странице чтобы показала по определенному ID данные, касательно него, при нажатии на кнопку. Выдает ошибку Trying to get property of non-object в основной странице, я думаю он не видит id который я ему посылаю сперва как GET-запрос.
Вот код функции:

```
public function updateTestIndex($id)
    {
        $roles = Roles::select('roles_user')->first();
        $roles = Roles::where('roles_user', '=', $roles)->get();

        $lectures = Lecture::all();

        $testingForm = TestingUsers::find($id);

        $testing = TestingUsers::all();

        return view('testing.editTesting', compact('roles', 'lectures', 'testing', 'testingForm'));
    }
```

Форма на которой хочу отобразить эти данные на редактирование:

```
    @foreach($testingForm as $test)
       <form class="lecture_form" action="{{route('editTest', $test->id)}}" method="post">
       {{ csrf_field() }}
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12-xxl col-lg-12 col-12 form-group">
                   <label>Вопросы теста </label>
                   <textarea type="text" name="question" class="form-control">{{$test->question}}</textarea>
              </div>   
              <div class="col-4-xxl col-lg-6 col-12 form-group">
                   <label>Вариант А </label>
                   <input type="text" name="optionA" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="{{$test->optionA}}">
              </div>   
              <div class="col-4-xxl col-lg-6 col-12 form-group">
                   <label>Вариант В </label>
                   <input type="text" name="optionB" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="{{$test->optionB}}">
              </div>   
              <div class="col-4-xxl col-lg-6 col-12 form-group">
                   <label>Вариант С </label>
                   <input type="text" name="optionC" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="{{$test->optionC}}">
              </div>   
              <div class="col-4-xxl col-lg-6 col-12 form-group">
                   <label>Вариант D </label>
                   <input type="text" name="optionD" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="{{$test->optionD}}">
              </div>   
              <div class="col-4-xxl col-lg-6 col-12 form-group">
                   <label>Правильный ответ</label>
                   <input type="text" name="correct_answer" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="{{$test->correct_answer}}">
              </div>  
              <div class="col-4-xxl col-lg-6 col-12 form-group">
                   <label>Выберите лекцию</label>
                   <select name="lecture_id" class="form-control">
                   @foreach($lectures as $lecture)
                         <option value="{{$lecture->id}}">{{ $lecture->name_lectures }}</option>
                   @endforeach
                   </select>
              </div>                             
              <div class="col-12 form-group mgt-8">
                   <button class="btn-fill-lg btn-yellow btn-hover">Сохранить</button>
              </div>
         </div>
   </form>
@endforeach
```

Вот еще web.php, на которой я опираюсь для данного случая:

```
Route::get('/editTests/{id}', 'Testing\TestingController@updateTestIndex')->name('updateTests');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужен цикл по переменной $testingForm, так как в ней содержится 1 элемент Eloquent коллекции. Достаточно просто `testingForm->prop` Плюс не совсем понятен код здесь, что вы хотите этим получить?

`$roles = Roles::select('roles_user')->first(); 
$roles = Roles::where('roles_user', '=', $roles)->get();`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Данный код я использую для определение ролей пользователь или админ

Comment: @ЕлдосКадыркул Тогда если вы хотите получить конкретно админов или пользователей, то можете просто например сделать так `$roles = Roles::where('roles_user', '=', AdminID)->get();`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ